# RMI, What is the modern day Java Equiv to .NET WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)?

Tags: c#, java, wcf, rmi

I'm old school java guy, I've been doing C# WCF, Remoting etc.... for over a decade.  When I left the java realm I was very proficient with [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation).  What is the current (WCF equiv) of Remoting in the java world?

Comment: By WCF, do you mean [Windows Communication Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) ([introductory article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee958158.aspx))? It's polite to at least include the full name with an acronym, and maybe even a link too, for the edification of the uninitiated.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked, [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) was a similar paradigm to WCF. Not sure if something "better" has emerged.

Note that Remoting and WCF are very different paradigms. I'm not sure what the equivalent Java framework for Remoting would be.

Answer (score 1):

Not my area of expertise, but…

This question, [how to implement SOA in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4201387/642706) ([about SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)), mentions [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/index.html) which unifies several frameworks including providing WS-* and [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web services with [Apache CXF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_CXF) (mentioned in [answer by Michael Gunter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21054175/642706)).

The extension of [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation), [Jini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jini), morphed into [Apache River](http://river.apache.org) is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1664949/642706).